# Is there anyway to have code-first migration in a web forms website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-migrations

When I create a new solution with "ASP.NET Web Forms Site" I can't enable or add any migrations.
here's the error that I get when I use "enable-migrations" or "add-migration SomeName":

> enable-migrations : you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

In many similar questions, the answers were about rebuilding solution or reinstalling EF or restarting Visual Studio. I've tried them all. the problem happens every time that I create a web forms site. I've also tested this in VS 2017 and VS 2022.

When I use "ASP.NET Web Application" template instead of "Web Site", I can enable and use migrations with no problems. but I couldn't find anything about the relation between code-first migrations and these two templates.

So maybe my question is can I use Web Site template and also have code-first migrations, or it's a must to use web app template?!

Comment: Hi, can you share the error code? This error is usually because there are null values in the data, and the get_value of ef cannot operate on null values. But it is difficult to give targeted opinions without exact code.

Comment: hi @wenbingeng-MSFT I'm just using the command "enable-migrtions" in nuget package manager console and i got the error that i mentioned in the question. ther'es no error on building solution or no error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my test, the problem you mentioned is real and I tried many methods but couldn't fix this problem. But then I stumbled upon this thing:

[image]

Yes, the ASP.NET Web Forms Site project type does not generate a csproj file. This means that Entity Framework does not work directly with ASP.NET Web Forms Site.

First of all, let's be clear that the csproj file is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration settings. Entity Framework is a popular .NET object-relational mapping (ORM) framework. The csproj file can be used to configure Entity Framework in a project by specifying the appropriate package references and configuration settings.

This means that when you execute enable-migrations, Entity Framework cannot obtain project-related configuration information and you cannot migrate.

Comment: So it means that there's no way to have migrations in a web forms website? or there is another solution for missing .csproj file?

Comment: @Hermit Yes, no csproj file means EF cannot be used. This is characteristic of this project type. Why not use other item types?

Comment: Hum, I am quite sure you can get EF to work with a web site as opposed to a web site application. However, I don't know if this setup could or would say support data migration from the class(s) to create the tables in the database. I would of course ensure that the EF models work. So, I'm not convinced this is not possible, but for now, unless someone steps in? It is a question of how to do this. For example, quite sure you have to use EF 5.x here, and 6.x will not work. EF and most nuget packages can be added to a web site as opposed to a web site application.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to test with EF 5.0. The work is progressing, but there are still errors. I'm trying to figure out how to overcome these difficulties.